# Spring-Boot testing: Bcrypt password encoder is not matching the password

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Trying to test `login` implementation for my spring-boot application. Code is very straightforward, not sure what is missing?

**UserController.java**

```
public BaseResponse login(@RequestBody UserCredential credential, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = tokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication(credential);
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) authentication
                .getDetails();
        UserDetails existingUser = userService.loadUserByUsername(credential.getUsername());

        if (existingUser == null || !passwordEncoder.matches(credential.getPassword(), existingUser.getPassword())) {

            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return BaseResponse.builder().status(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED).message("Incorrect credentials")
                    .build();
        } else {
            return BaseResponse.builder().status(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK).message(token).build();

        }
    }
@Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }
```

**UserControllerTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
public class UserControllerTest {
 @Test
    public void login(){
        try {

            UserCredential credentials = UserCredential.builder().username("test").password("password").build();
            dao.save(credentials);
            String response = mvc.perform(post("/login")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(credentials)))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>> Login response "+response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Just a guess, but could it be because the existingUser password was not saved in the encoded form (i.e. I think you are storing the "test" user password in plain text and not as a BCrypt encoded hash)?

Comment: @ShawnSherwood No. That is not the case. `test` user password is saved as BCrypt encoded hash.

Comment: Without seeing more code I can't say.  A couple of questions however - what is the purpose of the authentication and user object in the UserController?  Those variables don't appear to be used.  The @Bean passwordEncoder() doesn't appear to be used either (is that a local class variable?).  Have you stepped through the debugger and verified that the existingUser.getPassword() is set as you expect?